# Mat selection list inside of expansion panel

Tags: css, angular

I need to create a selection list with checkboxes inside of an expansion 
    expansion panel

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of Dataseource">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header style="display:flex" class="mat-row">
    {{datasource.showheader}}
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <div *ngFor="let match of Datasource; let i= index">

                      <mat-selection-list  [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
                            <mat-list-option [value]="match">
                              <div class="container-name">
                                <div class="col-6">{{match.Name }}  vs {{ match.Address }}</div>
                              </div>
                              <mat-divider [inset]="true" *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
                            </mat-list-option>
                          </mat-selection-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I should be able to select individual items and add to list object with header and selected items

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of Datasource">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header style="display:flex" class="mat-row">
    {{item.Name}}
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                      <mat-selection-list ngFor="let match of item.match; let i= index;" [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
                            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let match of item.match" [value]="match">
                              <div class="container-name">
                                <div class="col-6">{{match.Name }}  vs {{ match.Address }}</div>

                              </div>

                            </mat-list-option>
                          </mat-selection-list>

      </div>

      <hr>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: This is how I resolve it. I needed 3 levels of ngFor directives

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I have been down voted on this.

Surely I found the solution to a problem and can hopefully help someone.